# Module Reader Not Loading all modules

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following script designed to take any and all files of a given type and return an array of all values. However when I run the script it does not add any of the values that are in directories inside the module folder unless I just add subsequent arrays.

```
<?php

function get_modules($dir,$ftype) {
    $file = scandir($dir);

    $result = array();

    foreach($file as $key => $value) {
        if($value == "." || $value == "..") {
            // Do Nothing
        } else {
            if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $value)) {
                array_merge($result, get_modules($dir . "/" . $value, $ftype));
            } else {
                if(pathinfo($value,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == $ftype) {
                    array_push($result, $dir . "/" . $value);
                } else {
                    // Do Nothing
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$modules = get_modules("modules","txt");

print_r($modules);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [glob() with some modifications](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#106595)? See

```
if ( ! function_exists('glob_recursive')) {
    // Does not support flag GLOB_BRACE
    function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0) {
        $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
        foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir)
            $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
        return $files;
    }
}

function get_modules($ftype) {
    $result = glob_recursive($ftype);
    return $result;
}

$modules = get_modules("*.txt");
print_r($modules);
```

Comment: it was almost perfect all it needed was a way to limit the first directory to a single option thank you, I was unaware of this function

Comment: yeah just a small modification to remove "./" and confirm module directory and it's flawless for my needs